# How to get Ionic toggle on the left hand side of the label?

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I have a simple toggle and label in a ion-item:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-toggle checked="true"></ion-toggle>
    <ion-label>Aangemeld blijven</ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

I want to acheve that the toggle is placed on the left hand side of the label, but my result is:
[image]

I tried the floating-left and right, but it doesn't help.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use item-start attribute, it works for me and it's probably the most recommanded.

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-toggle item-start checked="true"></ion-toggle>
    <ion-label>Aangemeld blijven</ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these two class to override and show ion-toogle text on right side

```
.item-toggle .toggle
{
   left: 16px !important;
}
.item-toggle .ng-binding
{
   margin-left: 98%  !important;
}
```

Sample : https://codepen.io/codeandyou/pen/obvYOG

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your response! But you made a Ionic 1 example as far I can see. Do you have also an example in Ionic 2/3?

Comment: try this ion-buttons {
order: 1
}

Comment: I added it to the login.scss like this: page-login {
  ion-buttons { 
    order: 1 
  } .... but no result :(